# Trouble applying Hahn-Banach theorem in exercise

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, hahn-banach-theorem

The exercise is the following:
Let $X$ be a vector space over the real numbers and $p:X \to \mathbb{R}$ a sublinear functional. Show that if $x_0\in X$ then there exists a linear functional $F:X\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $F(x_0)=p(x_0)$ and $F(X) \leq p(x)$ for al $x\in X$.

I know this has Hahn-Banach Theorem written all over it and that the $F(x_0)=p(x_0)$ if $x_0=0$. I just don't find a way to do it for $x_0\neq 0$. Is there any path to do that?

Edit:
The Hahn Banach Theorem that I'm using states the following:
Let $M_0$ be a subspace of a Vector Space $X$ over $\mathbb{R}$, $p: X \to \mathbb{R}$  a sublinear functional and $f_0$ a linear functional defined only on $M_0$. Then there exists a linear functional $F: X\to \mathbb{R}$ such that:

1)$F(x)=f_0(x)$, for all $x\in M_0$
2) $F(x)\leq p(x)$, for all $x\in X$

Comment: Maybe you could state the Hahn-Banach Theorem version you are using. I guess the answer is very simple, but depends on the precise statement you are using.

Comment: Is there any positivity assumption on $p$?

Comment: Hi @AndréCaldas I've made an edit which states the HBT I'm using.

Comment: @JustDroppedIn yes. $p(x+y)\leq p(x)+p(y)$ and $p(\alpha \cdot x) = \alpha p(x)$, for all $x\in X$,  $\alpha\geq 0$

Comment: I mean, do we have $p(x)\ge0$ for all $x\in X$? As far as I know this is necessary to apply Hahn-Banach, at least that's what's stated in wiki

Comment: @JustDroppedIn As far as I know, no. In fact, we made a distinction is class that if we have $p(x)\geq 0$ for all $x$, we would call it a "Convex Functional". But we used $p$ as I stated in my previous comment to for the proof of HBT. And the exercise doesn't says $p$ is a convex functional, so I assumed it is just sublinear. Either way, I stated the HBT I used in my question just in case.

Comment: Now, just define $f_0(\alpha x_0) = \alpha p(x_0)$, and extend it using the theorem.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Consider $M_0=\operatorname{Lin}(x_0)$.